# Microsoft Graph API: Outlook calendar, obtener y crear eventos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, calendar, outlook, microsoft-graph

Estoy creando un web api en NODEJS que me envíe los eventos de un calendario de outlook, para ello uso la herramiente de microsoft graph. Intento que me envíe los eventos mediante el servicio de **/me/calendarview**.

Se me indica que para javascript necesito generar la conexión mediante este código.

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

let calendarView = await client.api('/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2021-12-07T15:27:39.993Z&enddatetime=2021-12-14T15:27:39.993Z')
    .get();
```

El problema es el siguiente:

Se requiere generar el authProvider mediante el servicio de  **https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?**
Este redirecciona a una página web de microsoft para la autenticación del cliente.

Necesito que esta autenticación se pueda hacer sin necesidad de entrar en un explorador web dado que debo crear un servicio completamente a través de peticiones.

Hay alguna manera de hacer esto ?

Comment: Ver si con un application password te permite ejecutar esas acciones

Answer (score 0):

Si, si revisas los cursos de Javascript se muestra como usando una secret y los datos de tenant y usuario lo puedes lograr:

`https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/auth/Office-Add-in-NodeJS-SSO` (ahí tienes varios ejemplos de como usarlos, recuerda usar una variable de entorno y pasar en la url de autenticación la SECRET)

Debes presetiar el token o para este caso la secret que generas desde él active directory e incluso le defines una caducidad de años para que sea funcional.